# Cannot connect to db server to specified port

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to set up db using docker. However I am facing the following issue that my port is not accepting following connections to this port. I've ran docker-compose up, all worked fine. Now I just can't connect to the server using pgAdmin.

Screenshot of error below:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gvcA.png)

Code src: https://github.com/khezen/compose-postgres

Comment: Can you edit the question, delete the image, and replace it with the actual code necessary to demonstrate the problem and the actual error message?  Please include these details as text as not images, and directly in the question and not behind links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your IP address is resolved in `pgadmin` service and localhost(127.0.0.1) resolved in `pgadmin` container, not in the host machine.

You should add a public or machine IP address or if both `pgadmin` and `postgres` service in the same network add the hostname of `postgres` service.

Comment: but I've used this setup in other machines and all worked fine https://github.com/khezen/compose-postgres Do I need to change the yml file or?

Comment: No, just use `postgres` Instead `localhost` in hostname/address field in pgadmin UI